# is there any option to show imageview in Grid according to width of screen in uitableview in swift

Tags: swift, image, uitableview

i want to show 3 images in a row of a `uitableview`. but if i have more than 3; it should in next row of table.

Here is the Code

```
 var abc = fileimage.count
for i in 0..<abc
{
    var tempimage = UIImage(named: fileimage[i])
    var actualwidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32
    var noofitem = actualwidth/100

    imageview.addSubview(fileimageview)
    fileimageview.easy.layout(Height(<=100))
    fileimageview.easy.layout(Width(<=100))

    fileimageview.easy.layout(Top(0),Left(0 * CGFloat(i) * 100),Bottom(0))
    fileimageview.image = tempimage
}
```

Comment: you can use collection view to achieve this grid layout

Comment: can u give me any example of it or link please

Comment: There are countless examples of using UICollectionView. Please do some searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a CollectionView with grid layout.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
        var fileimage = [UIImage]()
        @IBOutlet weak var showPhotosCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showPhotosCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.showPhotosCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fileimage.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell
        cell!.imageView.image = self.fileimage[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    //1
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
        UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        return CGSize(width: (screenWidth/3)-6, height: (screenWidth/3)-6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example you can achieve by dividing the width of your collection view by 3.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {    

      @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewFlowLayoutAction: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
      @IBOutlet weak var otherProvidersCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

          //Customize these properties per your need

            collectionViewFlowLayoutAction.itemSize = CGSize(width: otherProvidersCollectionView.frame.size.width/3.0, height: otherProvidersCollectionView.frame.size.width/3.0) // this will show only 3 grid per row according to your collectionview width.

            collectionViewFlowLayoutAction.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.5 
            collectionViewFlowLayoutAction.minimumLineSpacing = 1.8
            collectionViewFlowLayoutAction.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
            otherProvidersCollectionView!.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewFlowLayoutAction
     }
}
```